# Infix to Postfix absurd value

Tags: c, algorithm

I have written a program below to convert Infix expression to Postfix expression.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Stack{
    int top;
    int capacity;
    char *array;
}Stack;

int isEmpty(Stack *s){
    return s->top == -1;
}
char pop(Stack *s){
    char c;
    if(isEmpty(s))
        return -1;
    c = s->array[s->top];
    s->array[s->top--] = '\0';
    return c;
}

void push(Stack *s,char c){
    s->array[++s->top] = c;
}

char peek(Stack *s){
    return s->array[s->top];
}

char *toString(char c){
    char *str = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*2);
    str[0] = c;
    str[1] = '\0';
    return str;
}

int hasGreaterPriority(char c1,char c2){
    if(c1 == '*' && (c2 == '+' || c2 == '-'))
        return 1;
    else if(c1 == '/' && (c2 == '+' || c2 == '-'))
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

void infixtopostfix(char exp[]){
    int len = strlen(exp),i;
    char *out = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
    out[0] = '\0';

    Stack *stack = (Stack *)malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    stack->capacity = len;
    stack->top = -1;
    stack->array = malloc(sizeof(char)*len);

    for(i=0; i<len; i++){
        if(exp[i] >= 'a' && exp[i] <= 'z')
            strcat(out,toString(exp[i]));
        else if(exp[i] == ')'){
            while(peek(stack) != '(')
                strcat(out,toString(pop(stack)));
            pop(stack);
        }
        else{
            if(isEmpty(stack) || exp[i] == '(')
                push(stack,exp[i]);
            else if(hasGreaterPriority(peek(stack),exp[i])){
                strcat(out,toString(pop(stack)));
                push(stack,exp[i]);
            }
            else
                push(stack,exp[i]);
       }
    }
    /* UNTIL HERE */
    while(!isEmpty(stack))
        strcat(out,toString(pop(stack)));

    printf("Postfix Expression: %s\n",out);
}

int main(void) {
    char exp[] = "a+b*(c/d-e)/(f+g*h)-i\0";
    printf("Infix Expression: %s\n",exp);
    infixtopostfix(exp);
    return 0;
}
```

Problem is as follows:

In infixtopostfix method, prior to while indicated by "UNTIL HERE" out variable value seems to be correct. I checked with the help of gdb. After 2 iterations of while loop also the value in out variable seems to be fine. In the last iteration i.e. while adding + into out,the value becomes as follows

```
abcd/e-fgh*+/i-*\377\377\377\377\025+
```

How did `\377\377\377\377\025+` get added to out variable?

Expected value would be `abcd/e-fgh*+/i-*+`

Comment: try change to `char *out = (char *)malloc((len+1)*sizeof(char));`

Comment: Yes it works after making this change.Thanks BLUEPIXY for code and Jonathan Leffler for reasoning why I need to make such a change even after gdb printing out variable properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have allocated space for an empty string:

```
char *out = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
out[0] = '\0';
```

You then do:

```
strcat(out,toString(exp[i]));
```

There isn't enough space allocated to add anything to the end of `out`.  There might be a reallocation somewhere, but it is well hidden.

Stylistically, you have:

```
    if(exp[i] >= 'a' && exp[i] <= 'z')
        strcat(out,toString(exp[i]));
    else if(exp[i] == ')'){
        while(peek(stack) != '(')
            strcat(out,toString(pop(stack)));
        pop(stack);
    }
    else{
        if(isEmpty(stack) || exp[i] == '(')
            push(stack,exp[i]);
        else if(hasGreaterPriority(peek(stack),exp[i])){
            strcat(out,toString(pop(stack)));
            push(stack,exp[i]);
        }
        else
            push(stack,exp[i]);
   }
```

You could avoid a level of nesting with:

```
    if(exp[i] >= 'a' && exp[i] <= 'z')
        strcat(out,toString(exp[i]));
    else if(exp[i] == ')'){
        while(peek(stack) != '(')
            strcat(out,toString(pop(stack)));
        pop(stack);
    }
    else if(isEmpty(stack) || exp[i] == '(')
        push(stack,exp[i]);
    else if(hasGreaterPriority(peek(stack),exp[i])){
        strcat(out,toString(pop(stack)));
        push(stack,exp[i]);
    }
    else
        push(stack,exp[i]);
```

This is self-consistent; the original is not.

---

#### Valgrind report

I took your code, added `static` before each function except `main()` (mainly to get around my default compilation options), and then ran your code under [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) to get the output:

```
$ valgrind ./pfx-infix
==17722== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==17722== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==17722== Using Valgrind-3.9.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==17722== Command: ./pfx-infix
==17722== 
Infix Expression: a+b*(c/d-e)/(f+g*h)-i
==17722== Invalid write of size 1
==17722==    at 0x4C2BEF3: strcat (mc_replace_strmem.c:268)
==17722==    by 0x4005D4: main (pfx-infix.c:67)
==17722==  Address 0x51f2041 is 0 bytes after a block of size 1 alloc'd
==17722==    at 0x4C2935F: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:291)
==17722==    by 0x4004FF: main (pfx-infix.c:57)
==17722== 
==17722== Invalid read of size 1
==17722==    at 0x4C2BEC4: strcat (mc_replace_strmem.c:268)
==17722==    by 0x4005D4: main (pfx-infix.c:67)
==17722==  Address 0x51f2041 is 0 bytes after a block of size 1 alloc'd
==17722==    at 0x4C2935F: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:291)
==17722==    by 0x4004FF: main (pfx-infix.c:57)
==17722== 
==17722== Invalid write of size 1
==17722==    at 0x4C2BEE0: strcat (mc_replace_strmem.c:268)
==17722==    by 0x4005D4: main (pfx-infix.c:67)
==17722==  Address 0x51f2041 is 0 bytes after a block of size 1 alloc'd
==17722==    at 0x4C2935F: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:291)
==17722==    by 0x4004FF: main (pfx-infix.c:57)
==17722== 
==17722== Invalid read of size 1
==17722==    at 0x4C2BEC4: strcat (mc_replace_strmem.c:268)
==17722==    by 0x400726: main (pfx-infix.c:77)
==17722==  Address 0x51f2041 is 0 bytes after a block of size 1 alloc'd
==17722==    at 0x4C2935F: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:291)
==17722==    by 0x4004FF: main (pfx-infix.c:57)
==17722== 
==17722== Invalid write of size 1
==17722==    at 0x4C2BEE0: strcat (mc_replace_strmem.c:268)
==17722==    by 0x400726: main (pfx-infix.c:77)
==17722==  Address 0x51f2044 is 3 bytes after a block of size 1 alloc'd
==17722==    at 0x4C2935F: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:291)
==17722==    by 0x4004FF: main (pfx-infix.c:57)
==17722== 
==17722== Invalid write of size 1
==17722==    at 0x4C2BEF3: strcat (mc_replace_strmem.c:268)
==17722==    by 0x400726: main (pfx-infix.c:77)
==17722==  Address 0x51f2045 is 4 bytes after a block of size 1 alloc'd
==17722==    at 0x4C2935F: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:291)
==17722==    by 0x4004FF: main (pfx-infix.c:57)
==17722== 
==17722== Invalid read of size 1
==17722==    at 0x4C2BEC4: strcat (mc_replace_strmem.c:268)
==17722==    by 0x4006A9: main (pfx-infix.c:70)
==17722==  Address 0x51f2041 is 0 bytes after a block of size 1 alloc'd
==17722==    at 0x4C2935F: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:291)
==17722==    by 0x4004FF: main (pfx-infix.c:57)
==17722== 
==17722== Invalid write of size 1
==17722==    at 0x4C2BEE0: strcat (mc_replace_strmem.c:268)
==17722==    by 0x4006A9: main (pfx-infix.c:70)
==17722==  Address 0x51f2046 is 5 bytes after a block of size 1 alloc'd
==17722==    at 0x4C2935F: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:291)
==17722==    by 0x4004FF: main (pfx-infix.c:57)
==17722== 
==17722== Invalid write of size 1
==17722==    at 0x4C2BEF3: strcat (mc_replace_strmem.c:268)
==17722==    by 0x4006A9: main (pfx-infix.c:70)
==17722==  Address 0x51f2047 is 6 bytes after a block of size 1 alloc'd
==17722==    at 0x4C2935F: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:291)
==17722==    by 0x4004FF: main (pfx-infix.c:57)
==17722== 
==17722== Invalid read of size 1
==17722==    at 0x4C2BEC4: strcat (mc_replace_strmem.c:268)
==17722==    by 0x40061E: main (pfx-infix.c:86)
==17722==  Address 0x51f2041 is 0 bytes after a block of size 1 alloc'd
==17722==    at 0x4C2935F: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:291)
==17722==    by 0x4004FF: main (pfx-infix.c:57)
==17722== 
==17722== Invalid write of size 1
==17722==    at 0x4C2BEE0: strcat (mc_replace_strmem.c:268)
==17722==    by 0x40061E: main (pfx-infix.c:86)
==17722==  Address 0x51f204e is 13 bytes after a block of size 1 alloc'd
==17722==    at 0x4C2935F: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:291)
==17722==    by 0x4004FF: main (pfx-infix.c:57)
==17722== 
==17722== Invalid write of size 1
==17722==    at 0x4C2BEF3: strcat (mc_replace_strmem.c:268)
==17722==    by 0x40061E: main (pfx-infix.c:86)
==17722==  Address 0x51f204f is 14 bytes after a block of size 1 alloc'd
==17722==    at 0x4C2935F: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:291)
==17722==    by 0x4004FF: main (pfx-infix.c:57)
==17722== 
==17722== Invalid read of size 1
==17722==    at 0x4E7D3B1: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1630)
==17722==    by 0x4E858D8: printf (printf.c:35)
==17722==    by 0x400633: main (pfx-infix.c:88)
==17722==  Address 0x51f2041 is 0 bytes after a block of size 1 alloc'd
==17722==    at 0x4C2935F: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:291)
==17722==    by 0x4004FF: main (pfx-infix.c:57)
==17722== 
==17722== Invalid read of size 1
==17722==    at 0x4EAC184: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1330)
==17722==    by 0x4E7CF81: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1630)
==17722==    by 0x4E858D8: printf (printf.c:35)
==17722==    by 0x400633: main (pfx-infix.c:88)
==17722==  Address 0x51f2050 is 15 bytes after a block of size 1 alloc'd
==17722==    at 0x4C2935F: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:291)
==17722==    by 0x4004FF: main (pfx-infix.c:57)
==17722== 
==17722== Invalid read of size 1
==17722==    at 0x4EAC199: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1330)
==17722==    by 0x4E7CF81: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1630)
==17722==    by 0x4E858D8: printf (printf.c:35)
==17722==    by 0x400633: main (pfx-infix.c:88)
==17722==  Address 0x51f204f is 14 bytes after a block of size 1 alloc'd
==17722==    at 0x4C2935F: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:291)
==17722==    by 0x4004FF: main (pfx-infix.c:57)
==17722== 
==17722== Invalid read of size 16
==17722==    at 0x4EAC0DE: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1362)
==17722==    by 0x4E7CF81: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1630)
==17722==    by 0x4E858D8: printf (printf.c:35)
==17722==    by 0x400633: main (pfx-infix.c:88)
==17722==  Address 0x51f2040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 1 alloc'd
==17722==    at 0x4C2935F: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:291)
==17722==    by 0x4004FF: main (pfx-infix.c:57)
==17722== 
==17722== Invalid read of size 1
==17722==    at 0x4EAC100: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1362)
==17722==    by 0x4E7CF81: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1630)
==17722==    by 0x4E858D8: printf (printf.c:35)
==17722==    by 0x400633: main (pfx-infix.c:88)
==17722==  Address 0x51f2050 is 15 bytes after a block of size 1 alloc'd
==17722==    at 0x4C2935F: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:291)
==17722==    by 0x4004FF: main (pfx-infix.c:57)
==17722== 
Postfix Expression: abcd/e-fgh*+/i-*+
==17722== 
==17722== HEAP SUMMARY:
==17722==     in use at exit: 72 bytes in 20 blocks
==17722==   total heap usage: 20 allocs, 0 frees, 72 bytes allocated
==17722== 
==17722== LEAK SUMMARY:
==17722==    definitely lost: 51 bytes in 19 blocks
==17722==    indirectly lost: 21 bytes in 1 blocks
==17722==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17722==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17722==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17722== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==17722== 
==17722== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==17722== ERROR SUMMARY: 204 errors from 17 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
$
```

This clearly identifies the out of range memory accesses; it also happens to produce the 'correct' answer.  You also have a number of memory leaks that should be fixed.

Comment: GDB is displaying correct value of out after the strcat step.

Comment: That only tells you that when you look at the string as a string, it is OK.  The trouble is, you may have trampled over control data for `malloc()`, or other memory that it allocated for use elsewhere.  You might get away with blue murder (or your existing code) because `malloc()` often allocates a minimum of 8 bytes (32-bit builds) or 16 bytes (64-bit builds), so operations up to 8 or 16 bytes long will be overwriting space that `malloc()` allocated, but it is still outside the 1 byte of memory that you requested.  Use [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) to check for memory bound problems.

Comment: You might also have a null-termination problem; did you ensure that the string is null terminated.

Comment: strcat(arg1,arg2) takes 2 arguments arg1 and arg2 both being strings.Result is also string and is stored in arg1. So I didn't explicitly make arg1 null terminated.

Answer (score 2):

```
stack->array = malloc(sizeof(sizeof(char)*len));
```

Must be:

```
stack->array = malloc(len);
```

`sizeof(sizeof(char)*len))` = `sizeof(size_t)` (the type returned by the `sizeof` operator)

Comment: This too is a problem.  It probably allocates 4 (maybe 8, nominally it could be just 2) bytes of memory for the `stack->array`, instead of `len` bytes as would be intended.

Answer (score -1):

Visit here if you want to find an exact answer to convert infix into postfix and prefix. Here, I have programmed without using pointer. Therefore it will be easy to understand in the beginning [For infix expression to prefix and postfix](http://www.chromeearth.com/infix-prefix-postfix-expression-c-without-pointer/)

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please do not just provide a link to some site which does not **explicitly** contain the answer the question the user asked, it does not help in any sense.